# Very Strange JSAPI Visualization Charts slow loading

Tags: google-visualization

I know similar question have been asked earlier. But I rather explain mine because I feel there is a larger issue at hand.

Well I am working in a ASP.NET MVC environment. I have a set of jQuery and scripts being initialized in the _Layout.js file. I have added the https://www.goolge.com/jsapi at the end of all the remaining jQuery references. 
1. Now, lately, not always, but sometimes (which is frequent for the last 4 days actually)... I realized my Google charts were not loading or were loading extremely slowly.

2. I used fiddler, I used firebug etc, but the request stop and waits and waits and keeps waiting at the stage where browser calls "Sending request google...."
3. I assumed it was because of fiddler and firebug there was some delay, but it was not. So this is what I tried, whenever the problem occurs I immediately switched off all fiddlers and firebugs and opened Command prompt and did a ping www.google.com....surprisingly "Request Timed Out". I immediatly also opened browser and tried to open www.google.com at this moment... It searched and then suddenly redirected to google.co.in as I am located in India.

Now, did anybody face such similar problem recently? I hope this is temporary... or is there anything I am missing?